# keep query outside of "VIEW" in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am quite new to codeigniter.I am in a situation where i have two table and they have one to many relationship between them.The schema is the following.One is the employee table and the other is the table for vacation application

> employee(id,name),
>
> application(id,start_date,end_date,reason,user_id),

plan is to display all the application in a single page showing `start_date,end_date,reason and name`.For querying the `application` table i have a admin controller as only admin can query the `application` table.And there is another userController to get data from employee table.In admin Model i have the following query to get all applications

```
class Adminmodel extends CI_Model{
  public function fetchAllRequest(){
    $q=$this->db->get('application');
    if($q->num_rows()){
       return $q->result_array();
    }else{
       return false;
    }

   }
```

Admin controller is the following :

```
 class Admin extends CI_Controller{

         public function index(){
             $this->load->model('Adminmodel');
             $data['request']=$this->Adminmodel->fetchAllRequest();
             $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
         }

   }
    }
```

it bring me a result like this:

```
Array ( 

     [0] => Array ( 

         [id] =5 

         [start] => 05/04/2016 

         [end] => 05/12/2016 

         [reason] => sick [status] => Pending 

         [employee_id] => 1
```

I am giving a single row.There can be hundreds of applications .My problem is i need to grab the employee_id from each row and use it to ***fetch  name from employee table.***

***One solution is i can go through each row in a foreach loop inside view and for each of them i call the user model passing employee id and fetch data.***

If i do that ***i need to use user model inside "VIEW" which is not a MVC approach.How i can solve this problem***.Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CI 2: check Join
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select

In CI 3: check join
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

you can join both table by employee.id with application.user_id

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('application');
$this->db->join('employee', 'employee.id = application.user_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```